# Processing Acknowledgments with CAMEL?

Tags: java, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

I have clients sending request thru different ways like web request, http request , soap request or thru some other channel.

In Camel i receive it from respective endpoints to jms queue. From queue processor picks up the message. Now processor
needs to send the acknowledgemnt to clients based on their preference(which they have sent in incoming request).Preference
can be they would like receive acknowledgement thru webservice or jms or filesystem anything.

I think it can be done with http://camel.apache.org/request-reply.html bit somehow i am not able to proceed further. Basically i am not sure
how should i process the acknowledgement from processor to respective clients using CAMEL inbuilt capabilities. Any direction would be help?

**UPDATE:-** Client preference is stored in incoming request message from client. You can also assume its stored somewhere in system (db or property file)

Comment: How are the clients going to specify their perference?

Comment: @ Matthew Wilson See my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is the return address pattern that you are describing - https://camel.apache.org/return-address.html

There is some sample code in a junit test case here - http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/camel/trunk/components/camel-jms/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/jms/JmsInOnlyWithReplyToAsHeaderTest.java?view=markup

**EDIT: Adding some sample code from the link above to explain it better:**

So lets say we have the following endpoints defined below, we have a 
`from("direct:start")`, 
`from("activemq:queue:foo")` and
`from("activemq:queue:bar?disableReplyTo=true")`

In our actual test we call this code:

```
template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:start", "World", "JMSReplyTo", "queue:bar");
```

This sends a message to the `direct:start` endpoint with the body containing "World" and a header called `JMSReplyTo` with the value "queue:bar". Because we have specified this `JMSReplyTo` header, once the route is finished it will call whatever endpoint is defined in the headers value, in this case it will call the "queue:bar" endpoint.

```
@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
return new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:start")
            // must enable preserveMessageQos to force Camel to use the JMSReplyTo header
            .to("activemq:queue:foo?preserveMessageQos=true")
            .to("mock:done");

        from("activemq:queue:foo")
            .to("log:foo?showAll=true", "mock:foo")
            .transform(body().prepend("Bye "));

        // we should disable reply to to avoid sending the message back to our self
        // after we have consumed it
        from("activemq:queue:bar?disableReplyTo=true")
            .to("log:bar?showAll=true", "mock:bar");
    }
};
}
```

So how does this fit in with your use case? Well what will happen is the client, or some code you have written will specify the `JMSReplyTo` header with an endpoint that relates to how the response will be sent. So if they want the reply to be placed on a queue, then the `JMSReplyTo` header's value will be the specified queues endpoint.

Comment: Yes Mathew i am looking something like this. But i am not getting how process(replier) will send the reply message to different prferres channels like it can be file request/webservice/jms request to customer side. Can you bit elaborate or point me some good example of returnAddress something  on my requirement, Tried to google but could not find any relevant one :(

Comment: edited my answer with an explanation of the unit test

Comment: but i need to send the reply to client based on client preference. I am not getting  how can i send the reply to file system or  webservice  which are at client side?

Comment: Unless your server has access to the clients file system it won't be able to access it unless you use FTP or something similar. If the client exposes a webservice that is accessible to the server then surely you can just call it?

Comment: Assume my server has access to client specific directory where i can put my response. Now how i can achieve it with camel return address?

Comment: Are you using java dsl or spring dsl and I will code you a sample

Comment: i am using spring xml